# cython convert python to c limit

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to convert a simple, and stupid, script from Python to C:

```
#script.pyx
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

x = 5
```

So, following the tutorial I created setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize('script.pyx'))
```

When I try to run:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I have a correct c file like output but I have also this error:

```
tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
error: [WinError 2] Cannot find the specified file
```

From this result I got a doubt: with cython can I convert any Python script? Even the most complex? What are the limits? If I have a file that imports library and / or other classes?
Thank you

Comment: It has nothing to do with the complexity of the script. Cython cannot find your pyx file (typo in name, not in the same directory - only you can find it out)

Comment: Very strange....all the files are in the same directory... @ead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes we need to fully specify where the script is, instead of just typing the name of the file, you must enter the full path, or you gotta cd to the right directory,

"/home/userrr/Desktop/folder45/script.pyx"

Instead of "script.pyx"

Of it still does not work, uninstall python, re install python and the reinstall Cython, another issue could be the pyx source code, pyx source code should be different from Normal python language, check the cdef function, cdef Cythonize Language also